# display the array as a table in Kivy Python

Tags: python, arrays, layout, android-recyclerview, kivy

i am new in Kivy and have this issue : i have Two Arrays

```
X=[[1,2,3],    and            Sum-Rows= [[6],
   [4,5,6],                              [15], 
   [7,8,9]]                              [24]]
```

How can I display the elements of these arrays as a table in Kivy Python?

```
             first Value      Second Value      Third Value     Sum
first row        1                 2                 3           6
second row       4                 5                 6           15
third row        7                 8                 9           24
```

i think Recyclerview maybe the solution ?
thanks

Comment: Have a look at GridLayout. You can fill it with labels with your elements.

Comment: thanks for your feedback , perfect , how can i do it if it is a Dynamic Array ?

Comment: it's simple, GridLayout has such parameters as cols and rows. You can get the length of your lists with elements, change number of cols for example or both with rows, and then just fill it in `for` loop.

Comment: I wrote my code below , can you read it?

Answer (score 0):

this is my code : 
main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import numpy as np




Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)

Builder.load_file('MyMain.kv')



class MainWindow(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self.counter = 1
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_stuff)

    def add_stuff(self, *args):
        self.textlist = [TextInput()]
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='% Gas {} '.format(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[0])




    def addnewtextinput(self):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text='% Gas  ' + str(self.counter)))
        self.counter += 1
        self.textlist.append(TextInput())
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.textlist[-1])


    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keyboard == 13:  # 32 - Cpace key presssed Ascii

            self.getresult()


        if keyboard == 9 : # 13 - Enter key presssed Ascii
            self.addnewtextinput()



        b = [i.text.strip().split(" ") for i in self.textlist]

        X = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in b]

        for i in range(len(X)-1):

)
            if (len(X[i]) < len(X[i+1])):
                for _ in range(len(X[i+1]) - len(X[i])):
                    X[i].append(0)

            if (len(X[i+1]) < len(X[i])):
                for _ in range(len(X[i]) - len(X[i+1])):
                    X[i+1].append(0)
            print(X[i])

        print(X) # this is the Dynamic Array






class TextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def set_focus(dt):
            self.focus = True

        Clock.schedule_once(set_focus, .1)


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

MyMain.kv

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 40


    <MainWindow>:
        spacing : 10
        name: "erst"
        grid: grid.__self__
        rows:2
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            orientation: "horizon"
            padding: 2
            id:grid
            cols:2








    <TextInputX>
        focus: True
```

the List X is the Dynamic list 
how can i do dynamic GridLayout with flixble Cols and rows ?

Answer (score 0):

MainWindow is GridLayout itself, why are you adding one more GridLayout inside of it?
To dinamically change it you can do something like:

```
# if you are in MainWindow, which is GridLayout
self.clear_widgets()
# number of cols is length or your rows + 1 for sum
self.cols = len(X[0]) + 1
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in X[i]:
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(j))
    self.add_widget(Label(text=str(Sum-Rows[i][0])))
```

That's all.

Comment: thanks , if i input the 3. Textinput , i have this Error :   raise GridLayoutException(
 kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayoutException: Too many children in GridLayout. Increase rows/cols! 
how can i Increase  rows/cols!  ?

Comment: self.cols = 5 for example, or self.rows = 10

Comment: perfect thank you very much , now i try to make a table such as the Table above ,             "definition row" :first Value|||Second Value |||Third Value ||| ..... X Value |||Sum.
"definition col" :first row|||second row|||third row |||....Y row.
but I can't write a static name for the first column and the first row "definition row"&"definition col" how can i do it ?.